# How do I include image path in my spec file?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have an error when I'm including an image in *_spec.rb file in Ruby on Rails 6.0, I'm using rspec gem. I'm absolutly begginer in this framework, I believe error is relationed to windows path. I've read many post in Stack Overflow but I can't resolve yet. Content of my file is:

```
require "rails_helper.rb"
RSpec.feature "Admins pueden crear articulos" do
    scenario "con atributos validos" do
        visit "/"
        fill_in "Name", with: "Razones por las cuales aprender Ruby on Rails"
        fill_in "Content", with: "Es un gran lenguaje de programacion"
        attach_file "Main image",'D:/ProyectosPersonales/RubyProjects/blog/spec/images/avatar4.jpg'

        click_button "Guardar"
    end
end
```

I attach a screenshot with the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the doc](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FActions:attach_file)

1) some input element on the page should have a name, id, or label_text matching "Main image"

2) you should use relative (not absolute) path of the file, in your case `/spec/images/avatar4.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [File Fixtures](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-8/docs/file-fixture), and add a copy of your test image file to `spec/fixtures/files/images/avatar4.jpg`